# What does もとめたのココ mean?

Tags: translation

The full line I came across was this. I think it was a webcomic for mother's day.

ゴミ もとめたのココに

If the context helps, the character saying was holding a trash bag and saying this to his mother.

Would this translate to "I'm looking for a place with trash" or "I'm looking for place to take a out the trash."? Or does the もとめた here translate to "desire"?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This should be a typo for **ま**とめた, which is the past-form of [まとめる](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%BA%8F%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B).

Comment: It probably is. Thanks.

Comment: If you’re still confused about the sentence I recommend editing in the typo fix so it doesn’t get closed. (If that was it and you understand now don’t bother editing of course. :-)